# How to show every array object in react.js after specific time interval?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array with 3 elements. I want to loop through it such that after 3 seconds the next element of array is rendered in place of the previous one and if last element is rendered then it should restart again. It's like after 3 seconds I want to display the next element in place of previous one as like looping through the array but showing one element at a time. I have tried the following code for it.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './text.css';
const Text = () => {
    var work = ["fighting", "learning", "qwerty"];
    const [seconds, setSeconds] = useState(0);
    useEffect(() => {
        const interval = setInterval(() => {
            if(seconds===2) setSeconds(seconds => seconds = 0);
            else setSeconds(seconds => seconds + 1);
            console.log(seconds);
        }, 3000);
    }, []);

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>{work[seconds]}</h1>
        </div>
    );
}
 
export default Text;
```

It is successfully rendering elements one after another but can't render anything after the last element. Also on console the value of seconds is always showing 0.

Comment: Hi, try `if(seconds===2) setSeconds(0);` ;)

Comment: Do you want to re-render 3 different components each every 3seconds? infinitly?

Comment: @Davo same output. Nothing changed.

Comment: @jinongun after 3 seconds I want to display the next element in place of previous one as like looping through the array but showing one element at a time

Comment: Also `else setSeconds(seconds + 1);`

Comment: @Davo 

{ else setSeconds(seconds + 1); } is not even rendering the next element which it was doing earlier.

Comment: Also, remove the dependency array at the end of the `useEffect`, plus the previous 2 adjustments and it should work (I just tested it).

Comment: Ok, yes it did. Thanks a lot.

Comment: You're welcome @prinzu, your previous code logic was fine, you were just using the setSeconds function wrong. Also, I recommend reading this article about dependency arrays: https://medium.com/better-programming/understanding-the-useeffect-dependency-array-2913da504c44

Comment: @Dave That was an explained article. Thanks for being so supportive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were not getting the updated `second` value inside the setInterval.

Also, `clearInterval` in `useEffect`.

[Working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/prod-breeze-pobm7?file=/src/App.js)

**Refactored code**

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
      setSeconds(second => (second === 2 ? 0 : second + 1));
    }, 3000);

    return () => clearInterval(interval)
  }, []);
```

**Update:**

The console.log inside setInterval's callback will always be 0 because the `seconds` inside the setInterval's callback is the value taken when the callback was registered with setInterval.

To see up-to-date values of second, use another useEffect with `seconds` as dependency.

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("seconds", seconds);
  }, [seconds]);
```

Comment: Thanks, helped to re-render the array but the console is still always showing  value of seconds as 0. Can you explain for that?

Comment: hi - i have updated the ans with explanation....also updated the demo...just refresh the codesandbox link

Answer (score 4):

The issue is that the initial state value is enclosed in the scope of the callback and never updates the state value in the outer scope, but defining the callback outside allows the state to update. Also, increment an index value instead and take the modulus of the array length to always get a valid index.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const work = ["fighting", "learning", "qwerty"];

export default function App() {
  const [index, setIndex] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const tick = () => setIndex(i => i + 1);

    const id = setInterval(tick, 3000);
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>{work[index % work.length]}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit using an interval with react hook]

Comment: Okay , thanks for telling me the core concept behind it. Helped a lot.

Comment: Awesome solution Drew! Thanks